# Reverse Array Numbers

Tags: r

I got a matrix of numbers:

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
```

I need a version like this:

```
x<-c(4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,1)
```

It is just a reversed version of the first array. Are there any efficient ways of getting this other than maybe a brute force loop?

Comment: Can you please provide additional examples to make it clear what you want in more than this one case?

Comment: For fun: `tabulate(x)[x]`.  Obviously not useful for much more than the given example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A combination of `rep` and `unique` will do the trick:

```
> x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
> y <- rev(unique(x)) # Reversing elements
> rep(y,y)  
 [1] 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
```

You can also use `rle` as in:

```
>z <- rev(rle(x)$values)
>rep(z, z)
 [1] 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
```

Just for fun, also using `table` will help you

```
>y <- as.numeric(rev(names(table(x))))
>rep(y, y)
```

Comment: rle version seems to not work with the following vector: x<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9)

Comment: `rle` doesn't work for `x<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9)` as `length(x)` is 36 and `length(rep(z, z))` is 44.

Comment: here's a much simpler example of the problem @zx8754 points out: `x = c(1,1,1,2)`

Comment: If you're going to use `rle` you definitely will have to work `z$lengths` into your algorithm.  Maybe `z$values<-rev(z$values) ; inverse.rle(z)`  . But, sad to say,  the OP checked off an answer so now we'll never know what he really wanted so far as a general solution goes.

Answer (score 8):

For fun, here's an alternative (though @Jilber's approach was what I was originally thinking).

```
as.numeric(as.character(factor(x, labels = rev(unique(x)))))
# [1] 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
```

Comment: This is the only version so far that has worked for `x = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,5,5,3,3,3)`.

Comment: @eddi Since to me it is not clear from the question what the actual operation is supposed to be, I wonder what the expected output should be for this vector.

Comment: @Roland - Ananda's answer is basically what it's supposed to be - I added an answer with a little explanation, that should make clear what I think is the most straightforward interpretation of OP.

Comment: @eddi I understand your interpretation of the question. However, it is your interpretation and based on no input from the OP. Going to vote on the question accordingly now ...

Comment: @Roland, yeah I agree it's not obvious what OP's needs were (apparently resolved by one of the answers), but in the absence of further clarification from OP I think this interpretation is the most straightforward one and has max benefit for any future reader (while most of the others have very narrow and limited scope of applicability)

Comment: @eddi, I understand your point. But sometimes narrowing the scope leads to more efficient solutions (for that particular problem). For example, if you already know the data is sorted, then it's more efficient to calculate the median yourself (just pick the mid-value) than running `median` function.

Comment: @eddi Yes, you are allowed to think that. As you are allowed to downvote answers because they don't answer according to your interpretation of the question. Still, you'll probably understand that not everyone likes that.

Comment: @Roland I do, and that's fine

Comment: @Arun agreed, but proper answers of that sort would specify the trade-off limitations of their approach, which none of the answers did (e.g. none of them said - will work for this and that type of sequence only, assuming this and that [but it's awesome in that limited case, because this and that; you get the point]).

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach using `rle`

```
x <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9)
myrle <- rle(x)
myrle$values <- rev(myrle$values)
inverse.rle(myrle)
[1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5
[31] 4 4 4 3 3 2
```

If in the data in not sorted, for example in @eddi new example, we can sort the data and then apply basically the same approach

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,5,5,3,3)
myrle <- rle(sort(x))
ind <- match(x, sort(x))
myrle$values <- rev(myrle$values)
inverse.rle(myrle)[ind]
[1] 5 5 5 3 3 5 5 1 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 6):

a minimalistic approach:

```
(4:1)[x]
```

Comment: or as answered below `5-x`

Comment: @zx8754 this is a bit more general, because you can replace 4:1 by other things, e.g `letters[1:4]`. I believe that's what @user1637000 had in mind, actually

Comment: same comment as @zx8754's answer

Comment: it's quite unusual to systematically downvote answers that don't correspond to your own interpretation of the question. Must be a lot of work.

Comment: @baptiste 5-6 clicks and only because I thought the question was interesting and was disappointed by most of the answers

Answer (score 5):

Let's interpret this action as mirroring:

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)

mirrorfun <- function(x, axis)  axis-(x-axis)

mirrorfun(x,mean(unique(x)))
#[1] 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1

y<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9)
mirrorfun(y,mean(unique(y)))
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 2
```

Comment: it's probably worth mentioning that the result of running this on e.g. `c(1,3,4)` is `[1] 4.333333 2.333333 1.333333`

Comment: Yes, it is a different operation than some of the other answers. But it's one possible interpretation of the question (maybe not the most interesting one). And the interpretation is stated at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: fair enough, I don't think it's a particularly useful interpretation (and one has to deduce from the answer what you mean by 'mirroring'), but your point stands

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
5-x
```

Or even better:

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
max(x)+1-x
```

Comment: Yeah -- I was going to post along this line. The OP didn't define what "reverse" really means, so why not "flip" every value about the value `mean(unique(x))` ?   If he wants to "reverse" the existing **values**, then he'd have to "flip" the values based on the output of `rank(x)`  or something like that.

Comment: Pretty weak interpretation imo, see e.g. `x = c(1,4,5)`.

Comment: @eddi The OP gave simple input and simple desired output, and answer provided satisfies the desired output. There is not much room for "interpretation". In addition, there is no other answer that is shorter and simpler.

Comment: Interpreting OP in the narrowest way possible is not a good answer imo. It might work for OP, but will not for anyone else who runs into a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I like Ananda's solution except for the fact that it converts numbers to characters and then back. It's actually the only one so far that correctly maps anything that's slightly more complicated than OP, e.g. `x = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,5,5,3,3)` (where the mapping would be `1<->5` and `2<->3` - note: this is really the only interpretation of OP that can make sense for anything outside of sorted sequences).

One alternative way to do the mapping, without converting to factors is the following:

```
library(data.table)

x = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,5,5,3,3)
data.table(x.in = unique(x), key = 'x.in')[, x.out := rev(x.in)][J(x)][, x.out]
#[1] 5 5 5 3 3 5 5 1 1 2 2
```

What the above does is, it creates a `data.table` with unique values from `x`, keys (and thus sorts) by that, creates the mapping (which is simply the reverse of the sorted unique's), and then merges with `x` to find the mapped result.

Comment: +1 for an interesting use of `data.table`. Are these "retaliation" downvotes or something? Or just expression of disagreement about your interpretation?

Comment: @AnandaMahto given that our answers produce the same results, I'd rule out the latter

Comment: @eddi thanks for adding this test case. I updated my answer, though I found this answer quite long now.

Comment: @dickoa it's interesting to note that @Ananda's answer does best when `x` is very small, and this one does worst (too much `data.table` overhead), but the way they scale - for medium `x` yours becomes better and for large `x` this one wins out